# Difference between PORT and LAT on an PIC18F

Tags: pic, microchip, pic18

I am currently working on a PIC18F and I wonder what the difference is between a `PORT` and a `LAT` because looking at the documentation of the PIC18F they both do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

A write to the `PORTx` register writes the data value to the port latch.
A write to the `LATx` register writes the data value to the port latch.
A read of the `PORTx` register reads the data value on the I/O pin.
A read of the `LATx` register reads the data value on the port latch.

Use `LATx`: to write to an output pin

Use `PORTx`: to read an input pin

For all PICs with `LATx` registers, all INPUT must be from `PORTx` and all OUTPUT should be to `LATx`, which totally avoids the problem of flipping bits when you write to a single bit of the port.

Comment: thanks you for explanation